# return The optimal set of items that should be put in the knapsack JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am currently working knapsack problem to return the set of the optimal solutions.

this is my method for that:

```
public static int knapsackArray(int val[], int wt[], int W) {
    //Get the total number of items. 
    int N = wt.length;

    //Create a matrix. 
    int[][] V = new int[N + 1][W + 1]; 

    //all columns at row 0 to be 0
    for (int col = 0; col <= W; col++) {
      V[0][col] = 0;
    }

    //Fill the first row with 0
    for (int row = 0; row <= N; row++) {
      V[row][0] = 0;
    }

    for (int item=1;item<=N;item++){
      for (int weight=1;weight<=W;weight++){
        if (wt[item-1]<=weight){
          V[item][weight]=Math.max (val[item-1]+V[item-1][weight-wt[item-1]], V[item-1][weight]);
        }
        else {
          V[item][weight]=V[item-1][weight];            
        }
      }
    }

    //Printing the matrix
    for (int[] rows : V) {
      for (int col : rows) {
        System.out.format("%5d", col);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    return V[N][W];
  }
```

and I have this other method that takes an Item set and a budget as arguments and it returns a Set of optimal solutions for this problem:

```
public static Set<Item> knapsack(Set<Item> items, int budget) {
    //create array of wieghts
    int[] weights = new int[items.size()];
    //create array of values
    int[] values = new int[items.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (Item x : items){
      weights[i] = x.getWeight();
      values[i] = x.getValue(); 
      //System.out.println(x);
      i++;
    }
    /*int N = weights.length;
    int[][] V = new int[N + 1][budget + 1];*/

    int j = knapsackArray(values, weights, budget);
    System.out.println(j);
    return null;
  }
```

my question if how can I make this matrix into the set of the items that are optimal. is this - my approach - even a good way to go for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the values matrix you create, inside `knapsackArray`, you can create a second matrix to keep track of how you gotten to that point. (i.e. the last element you took) That way, once you're done with your DP solution, you can trace back all the elements you have gotten on your way. Also, in order to be able to pass the value back to `knapsack`, you need to pass a set parameter down to `knapsackArray`.

Below is a crude demonstration of the method I outlined.

```
public static int knapsackArray(int val[], int wt[], int W, Set<int> itemIndices) {
    // ...

    // Create a matrix. 
    int[][] V = new int[N + 1][W + 1]; 
    int[][] G = new int[N + 1][W + 1]; 

    // ...

    for (int item=1;item<=N;item++) {
        for (int weight=1;weight<=W;weight++) {
            if (wt[item-1]<=weight) {
                int candidate = val[item-1] + V[item-1][weight-wt[item-1]];
                if(candidate > V[item-1][weight]) {
                    V[item][weight] = candidate;
                    G[item][weight] = item - 1;
                }
                else {
                    V[item][weight] = V[item-1][weight];
                    G[item][weight] = -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                V[item][weight]=V[item-1][weight];
                G[item][weight] = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    int currentItem = N;
    int currentWeight = W;
    while(currentItem >= 1) {
        if(G[currentItem][currentWeight] >= 0) {
            itemIndices.add(currentItem - 1);
            currentWeight = currentWeight - wt[currentItem - 1];
            currentItem = G[currentItem][currentWeight] + 1;
        }
        else {
            currentItem = currentItem - 1;
        }
    }

    // ...

    return V[N][W];
}
```

Once you do this, you can actually process the indices within that parameter `Set<int> itemIndices` and populate the `Set<Item> items` in `knapsack` method, as given below.

```
public static Set<Item> knapsack(Set<Item> items, int budget) {
    // ...

    Set<Item> itemsToAdd;
    Set<int> itemIndices;
    int j = knapsackArray(values, weights, budget, itemIndices);
    int i = 0;
    for (Item x : items) {
        if(itemIndices.contains(i)) {
            itemsToAdd.add(x);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return itemsToAdd;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I have one question, at "while(item >= 1) " what is the value of item here, since its outside of the for-loop, what should this be initialized to?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo

Comment: Umm..I'll try and debug/update my code if you can provide a sample input and output case in your question.

Comment: some tests: ` @Test
  public void testTwoItemsOneFits() {
    Set<Item> items = buildSet(new Item(2, 20), new Item(10, 2));
    assertEquals(buildSet(new Item(2, 20)), Solution.knapsack(items, 2));
  }`

Comment: `@Test
  public void testNoItems() {
    assertEquals(buildSet(), Solution.knapsack(buildSet(), 42));
  }

  @Test
  public void testOneItemFits() {
    Set<Item> items = buildSet(new Item(10, 20));
    assertEquals(new HashSet<>(items), Solution.knapsack(items, 15));
  }`

Comment: I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for the last 2!

Comment: sorry my bad,  I had some typos, however this still fails: `testTwoItemsOneFits` for this i still get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: i kind of fixed it but now i pass only half of the tests, my question is why do I have to add to items once i made the itemIndices?

Comment: That was a naming mistake on my part. You should use a separate set to add the `Item` instances, not the `items` parameter in `knapsack` function. I updated my code accordingly.